# How to make sonarqube ignore the equals and hashcode

Tags: sonarqube, test-coverage

I'm wondering if it is currently possible to ignore the equals and hashcode method for the sonar test coverage? I have heard about the block exclusion, but it didn't work.

Comment: Your question is interesting. Can you show what have you tried?

Comment: i have tried to edit the pom.XML with the sonar.coverage.exclusions Statement like this:  *public int hashCode()*} , but it didn't work.  @RAS

Comment: I understand your point. Please edit your question & put all these details there.

Comment: As of May 2019, this appears to not be possible.  https://community.sonarsource.com/t/is-there-a-way-to-exclude-java-equals-hashcode-methods-from-code-duplication/9118

Answer (score 2):

(assuming you're using jacoco for coverage reporting)

If you're not using Lombok, you might try adding the @Generated annotation to your methods you want skipped. I'm not sure this will work - but worth a shot!

If you're using Lombok [like I was], here's a solution from Rainer Hahnekamp that marks the code as @Generated, which makes jacoco ignore the methods, and in turn makes sonarqube display a higher coverage percentage.

> Luckily, beginning with version 0.8.0, Jacoco can detect, identify, and ignore Lombok-generated code. The only thing you as the developer have to do is to create a file named lombok.config in your directory’s root and set the following flag:

`lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true`

> This adds the annotation lombok.@Generated to the relevant methods, classes and fields. Jacoco is aware of this annotation and will ignore that annotated code.
>
> Please keep in mind that you require at least version 0.8.0 of Jacoco and v1.16.14 of Lombok.

https://www.rainerhahnekamp.com/en/ignoring-lombok-code-in-jacoco/